# Authentication error when connecting to Postgres in a Docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to a Postgres database inside a Docker container. I'm using pgAdmin 4 on windows as my client.

`Password does not match for user "postgres".`

My docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes: 
  pgdata:
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. The file states that the username and password are both `postgres`. I was able to connect when I just `docker run` the image. Now I'm using the compose file I seem to be getting this problem.

Answer (score 4):

Fixed by doing the following:

- Stopped container.
- Removed container.
- Removed volume.

Volume must have contained previous configuration.

Comment: For me it didn't work even if you are right. Looks like old password has been stored somewhere deeper. So I had to change password back... And then connect to the running container and change it through `alter user`

Comment: The key seemed to be removing the container and volume to completely clear it up.